# How do I get the parent shell's path on windows in pure python?

Tags: python, windows, shell

The following will return the shell that launched the current process & the shell's full path. However, it uses a python library full of c extensions. Sometimes a shell launches a shell, etc. I'm just looking for the "most recent ancestor" process that is a shell.

How do I do this with just pure python? (i.e. no c extensions, using windll.kernel32 and the like are fine- of course at some point to get process info code will have to access platform-specific native code, it just needs to be something already buried in the python standard library, not something that needs compiling c)

[Shellingham at the moment can't do this](https://github.com/sarugaku/shellingham/issues/42).

```python
from typing import Tuple, List

import os

import psutil

SHELL_NAMES = {
    'sh', 'bash', 'dash', 'ash',    # Bourne.
    'csh', 'tcsh',                  # C.
    'ksh', 'zsh', 'fish',           # Common alternatives.
    'cmd', 'powershell', 'pwsh',    # Microsoft.
    'elvish', 'xonsh',              # More exotic.
}

def find_shell_for_windows() -> Tuple[str,str]:
    names_paths:List[Tuple[str,str]]=[]
    current_process = psutil.Process(os.getppid())
    process_name, process_path = current_process.name(), current_process.exe()
    names_paths.append((process_name, process_path))
    for parent in current_process.parents():
        names_paths.append((parent.name(), parent.exe()))
    for n,p in names_paths:
        if n.lower() in SHELL_NAMES or n.lower().replace(".exe","") in SHELL_NAMES:
            return n,p
    return ["",""]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_shell_for_windows())
```

Comment: What is a shell?

Comment: for example cmd.ex, or bash.exe - applications (processes), launched form a shell will have a parent process with a name and a path, e.g. bash.exe, path of c:\program files\etc...

Comment: So if I take a copy of Bash and name it `shab.exe`, it’s not a shell?

Comment: correct. The names of the shells are listed in the code snippet, sh, bash, etc. if the process is named shab.exe or anything else, it is safe to assume it is not a shell. We're not trying to handle the scenario where a user is trying to hide the shell they're using.

Comment: `import os` is for the `os.getppid()` which gets the process id. It looks like `relative_to` is for path manipulation if you already have a path. The trick is to get the path to the shell that launched the current process in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about looking for a way to walk the list of ancestor processes and find the first whose executable matches an item in a hardcoded list of names, hoping that it will be the user’s ‘shell’. Before I answer it, here are some reasons why this is an absolutely stupid and useless thing to do:

- The executable you are looking for may be named something else from what you expect. In a comment to the question I gave an example of naming the Bash executable `shab.exe`, which the asker dismissed with the punchline of the well-known doctor joke (‘well, don’t do that then’) as the user trying to ‘hide’ their shell. But this can happen even without any ‘spiteful’ intent to ‘hide’ something on the user’s part. For example, the user may have several versions of Bash installed with different executable names (`bash-4.00.exe`, `gitbash.exe`, etc.), in order to test whether their scripts are compatible with all of them. Are you going to enumerate every single possible name in your code? Or are you going to match all executables with `sh` in their name and cross fingers that there aren’t any false positives?
- Conversely, [just because an executable has the name you expect, it doesn’t mean it will have the behaviour you expect](https://askubuntu.com/a/946218). This is even more true on Windows, where there isn’t really a standardised set of executable names that should always have specific, prescribed behaviour. And this is *especially* true if you indiscriminately lump programs like `cmd`, `bash`, `fish` and `xonsh` together under the name of ‘shell’: these programs accept different syntaxes on their own command lines and within their respective scripting languages. Unless all you want to do is launch the shell for the user to interact with, you’re going to be looking for the specific *kind* of the shell – whether it’s a POSIX-compatible shell, a DOS-derived shell like `cmd` or something else completely – in order to take advantage of its particular behaviours. Merely knowing that it’s ‘a shell’ doesn’t actually tell you anything useful. And let’s not forget that not all shells are even command lines – Windows Explorer is a shell, after all.
- Even if executable names did line up perfectly, there is no way a hardcoded list is going to be exhaustive. The asker’s list already omits [`tcmd`](https://jpsoft.com/products/take-command.html) or [`tclsh`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/UserCmd/tclsh.htm). I hear some crazy people use Python itself as a shell – who are you to stop them? If a new shell appears, it will have to be added as another entry in the list; let’s hope there is still someone who remembers where it is then.
- Though let’s say for the sake of the argument that we’re only interested in command-line shells and ignore everything else. What if the script is launched from an Explorer process that was itself started from Bash? The script is going to ignore the Explorer process and pick Bash as the ‘shell’, even though it’s clearly Explorer and not Bash which launched the script. Is this correct or desired? I think the answer is far from obvious.

But if the above doesn’t deter you from this futile task (or perhaps you want to do something similar for a *more* sensible purpose), here’s how you can accomplish this nonsensical thing anyway:

```
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes, contextlib

k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 18
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122
TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 2
PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000

def _check_handle(error_val=0):
    def check(ret, func, args):
        if ret == error_val:
            raise ctypes.WinError()
        return ret
    return check

def _check_expected(expected):
    def check(ret, func, args):
        if ret:
            return True
        code = ctypes.GetLastError()
        if code == expected:
            return False
        raise ctypes.WinError(code)
    return check

class ProcessEntry32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('dwSize'             , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('cntUsage'           , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('th32ProcessID'      , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('th32DefaultHeapID'  , ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.ULONG)),
        ('th32ModuleID'       , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('cntThreads'         , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('th32ParentProcessID', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('pcPriClassBase'     , ctypes.wintypes.LONG),
        ('dwFlags'            , ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('szExeFile'          , ctypes.wintypes.CHAR * ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH),
    )

k32.CloseHandle.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,)
k32.CloseHandle.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL

k32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD)
k32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
k32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.errcheck = _check_handle(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

k32.Process32First.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(ProcessEntry32))
k32.Process32First.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
k32.Process32First.errcheck = _check_expected(ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)

k32.Process32Next.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(ProcessEntry32))
k32.Process32Next.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
k32.Process32Next.errcheck = _check_expected(ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)

k32.GetCurrentProcessId.argtypes = ()
k32.GetCurrentProcessId.restype = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD

k32.OpenProcess.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.BOOL, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD)
k32.OpenProcess.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
k32.OpenProcess.errcheck = _check_handle(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

k32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW.argtypes = \
    (ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.LPWSTR, ctypes.wintypes.PDWORD)
k32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
k32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW.errcheck = _check_expected(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def Win32Handle(handle):
    try:
        yield handle
    finally:
        k32.CloseHandle(handle)

def enum_processes():
    with Win32Handle(k32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)) as snap:
        entry = ProcessEntry32()
        entry.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(entry)
        ret = k32.Process32First(snap, entry)
        while ret:
            yield entry
            ret = k32.Process32Next(snap, entry)

def get_full_path(proch):
    size = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH)
    while True:
        path_buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('', size.value)
        if k32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW(proch, 0, path_buff, size):
            return path_buff.value
        size.value *= 2

SHELLS = frozenset((
    b'sh.exe', b'bash.exe', b'dash.exe', b'ash.exe',
    b'csh.exe', b'tcsh.exe',
    b'ksh.exe', b'zsh.exe', b'fish.exe',
    b'cmd.exe', b'powershell.exe', b'pwsh.exe',
    b'elvish.exe', b'xonsh.exe',
))

def find_shell_for_windows():
    proc_map = {
        proc.th32ProcessID: (proc.th32ParentProcessID, proc.szExeFile)
        for proc in enum_processes()
    }

    pid = proc_map[k32.GetCurrentProcessId()][0]
    proc = proc_map[pid]
    while proc:
        ppid, name = proc
        if name in SHELLS:
            with Win32Handle(k32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 0, pid)) as proch:
                return get_full_path(proch)
        pid, proc = ppid, proc_map.get(ppid)

if __name__ = '__main__':
    print(find_shell_for_windows())
```

The above does exactly what was asked, using only `ctypes`, and should work on Windows Vista and above (tested with Python 3.8 on Windows 7). For older Windows versions, some Win32 calls will probably have to be changed (most of all, `QueryFullProcessImageNameW`).

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for, I'm going to try it out as soon as I get out of all these meetings :-)

Comment: Oh I don't disagree that this is stupid, but `poetry` relies on this sort of logic, which is broken on windows. This just seemed the easier way to get the maintainers to fix it.